# TestCafe typed Context giving "property is missing in type { [key: string]: any; }" error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, testcafe

I've been using Typescript for a little bit now, but every once in awhile something comes up that really stumps me.

Given the code in this [Github issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4911), the function passed into any test hook using a typed context gives an error of: `Property 'color' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: any; }' but required in type 'MyContext'`

Here is the code from the Github issue that causes the problem:

```
interface MyContext {
    color: string
}

interface TestControllerEx<TContext> extends Omit<TestController, 'ctx'> {
    ctx: TContext;
}

fixture`Fixture1`.beforeEach(async (t: TestControllerEx<MyContext>) => {
    t.ctx.color = 'red' // strongly typed!
});

test('Test1', async (t: TestControllerEx<MyContext>) => {
    await t.expect(t.ctx.color).eql('red'); // 'red' strongly typed!
});
```

I could type the `color` property in `MyContext` as optional, and that's currently how I'm getting around this, but I would like to understand why this is happening.

The TestCafe `TestController` interface types the ctx property as `{ [key: string]: any }`.  Shouldn't the generic type being passed into `TestControllerEx` be enough to satisfy this condition?  I've even tried making TContext extend the `{ [key: string]: any }` index signature directly without any luck.

Does this have something to do with TestCafe's typings or is it a Typescript specific thing that I'm not understanding?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no good way to achieve your goal. A more or less suitable way is to override the `FixtureFn` interface and use the `fixture` object as its implementation.

***`get-fixture-with-custom-ctx.ts` file:***

```js
import 'testcafe';

export function getFixtureWithCustomCtx<MyContext> () {
    interface TestControllerEx extends TestController {
        ctx: MyContext;
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    interface MyFixture extends FixtureFn {
        beforeEach: (fn: (t: TestControllerEx) => Promise<any>) => MyFixture;
    }
    return fixture as MyFixture;
}
```

***`test.ts` file:***

```js
import { getFixtureWithCustomCtx } from './fixture';

interface MyContext {
    color: string;
}

const fixture = getFixtureWithCustomCtx<MyContext>();

fixture`My fixture`
    .page('about:blank')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        t.ctx.color = 'red';
        t.ctx.style = 'inline';
    });

test('Test1', async t => {
    await t.expect(t.ctx.color).eql('red');
});
```

Thus, the TS rules will be violated only in one file from which you can export the fixture with the desired context anywhere.

Comment: I do like this approach, thank you for the example!  This does work on my end and I may consider adopting this in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Typescript specific thing. In this example, `TestControllerEx` extends all `TestController` properties on the top level, but does not do this for embedded properties, for `ctx` namely. After that it overrides `ctx` properties to a more strong type. That is why you cannot set any arbitrary value in the `ctx` property. To resolve this problem you can add another definition in the `MyContext`, like this:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

interface MyContext {
    color: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface TestControllerEx<TContext> extends Omit<TestController, 'ctx'> {
    ctx: TContext;
}

fixture`Fixture1`.beforeEach(async (t: TestControllerEx<MyContext>) => {
    t.ctx.color = 'red' // strongly typed!
    t.ctx.style = 'inline ' // strongly typed!
});

test('Test1', async (t: TestControllerEx<MyContext>) => {
    await t.expect(t.ctx.color).eql('red'); // 'red' strongly typed!
});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying so I tried adding the `[key: string]: any` signature to `MyContext`.  It looks like the original Typescript error is still happening in my environment.  I tried a fresh install of TestCafe just to eliminate any configuration issues but had no luck either.

Comment: Please share your full example, because I don't have any problem when I try to define other properties than this one with this interface. I updated the code in my answer to the full version to be clearest.

Comment: The example I gave in my initial question is the only code that I'm using in a fresh directory with TestCafe v1.19.0 installed locally.  Everything is setup according to the [local install instructions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402834/guides/basic-guides/install-testcafe#local-installation).  I can run the test just fine without issue, but VS Code is giving me that same error on the fixture argument: `Property 'color' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: any; }' but required in type 'MyContext'`.  Could this be editor related then?  Possibly an npm global install thing?

Comment: Yes, I tried this example in the VS Code and got this error as well. It happens because VS Code has its own default TS options. The easiest way to bypass this error is to create your own `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I created my own `tsconfig.json` file and it does prevent the error.  The more specific option that causes this type error is the `strictFunctionTypes` flag.  This option seems very helpful, so I'd like to keep it enabled.  Because of this, I don't think there's a way to not type my test context properties as optional, is there?  Either way, I appreciate all the help!